# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbListTables': object 'chinook' not

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I am trying to pull up a data table for a database. However, this code keeps showing up, and I have no idea how to approach it.

For reference, here is the work I have done so far.

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
setwd("C:/Users/cliff/Downloads/MIS431/Chinook.db")
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")
chinook <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="Chinook.db")
dbListTables(chinook)'
```

I expected the code to show...

```
`dbListTables
[1] "Album"       "Artist"        "Customer"   "Employee"
[5] "Genre"       "Invoice"       "InvoiceLine" "MediaType"
[9] "Playlist"    "PlaylistTrack" "Track"`
```

When I run the code, this pops up

```
`dbListTables(chinook)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbListTables'
object 'chinook' not found
```

Let me know what I can do to pull up the data table. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ty - error messages are often very informative. This error message says that the "object `chinook` cannot be found". That means there may be an error in the line `chinook <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="Chinook.db")` - since this isn't reproducible, it will be hard to debug further. Good luck!

Comment: I looked over the code and I found that there was an error with the working directory. But now after fixing that, this shows up                                                      dbListTables(chinook)
character(0)